# COM Interop Not Detecting .NET Functions Via Interface

Tags: c#, .net, com

I have a **.NET assembly** that I have executed `regasm` and `gacutil`. I also have a **COM interop** that I am trying to get to work with the **.NET assembly**. However, through my `pDotNetCOMPtr` I am not able to "detect" any of the methods on my .NET public interface. The MFC COM DLL keeps saying that there is not method called `Encrypt` in `_SslTcpClientPtr` when I try to compile with Visual Studio 2010. I am using the .NET 4.0 Framework. Thoughts?

### COM / MFC

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BSTR __stdcall Encrypt(BSTR encryptString)
{   
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    ICVTnsClient::_SslTcpClientPtr pDotNetCOMPtr;

    HRESULT hRes = pDotNetCOMPtr.CreateInstance(ICVTnsClient::CLSID_SslTcpClient);

    if (hRes == S_OK)
    {
        BSTR str;

        hRes = pDotNetCOMPtr->Encrypt(encryptString, &str);     

        if (str == NULL) {
            return SysAllocString(L"EEncryptionError");
        }
        else return str;    
    }

    pDotNetCOMPtr = NULL;

    return SysAllocString(L"EDLLError");

    CoUninitialize ();
}
```

### .NET

```
namespace ICVTnsClient
{
    [Guid("D6F80E95-8A27-4ae6-B6DE-0542A0FC7039")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface _SslTcpClient
    {
        string Encrypt(string requestContent);
        string Decrypt(string requestContent);        
    }

    [Guid("13FE33AD-4BF8-495f-AB4D-6C61BD463EA4")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class SslTcpClient : _SslTcpClient
    {

       ...
       public string Encrypt(string requestContent) { // do something }

       public string Decrypt(string requestContent) { // do something }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it Visual C++ one the C++ side or some other C++ implementation?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758990/register-for-com-interoperability

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863128/c-sharp-exposing-to-com-interface-inheritance?rq=1

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932183/net-to-com-interop-tester?rq=1

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631120/com-interface-guid?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you forgot the [InterfaceType] attribute so that the interface can be early-bound and the method names appear in the type library.  Fix:

```
[Guid("D6F80E95-8A27-4ae6-B6DE-0542A0FC7039")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface _SslTcpClient
{
    // etc..
}
```

ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual allows it to be both early and late bound.  Microsoft prefers the default, IsIDispatch, less ways to shoot your foot with late binding.